# PHP SQL select with OR

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am wondering if there is such command as to select a item from the database based on 2 or more rows.

For Example:

```
SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE 'row1' OR 'row2' OR 'row3' LIKE 'myValue'
```

is there such thing as OR ?

Comment: I assume you mean based on 2 or more columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you need to specify each condition explicitly:

```
WHERE row1 LIKE 'myValue'
   OR row2 LIKE 'myValue'
   OR row3 LIKE 'myValue'
```

Important notes:

1. Don't use `quotes` (`'`) around column names. Only backticks `` ` `` are allowed
2. If you don't use `LIKE` facilities like `_` or `%` - don't use it, and use `=` instead. In this case your condition can be reduced to:

   ```
   WHERE 'myValue' IN (row1, row2, row3)
   ```

Comment: @diEcho: thanks. Didn't know how to do the trick with backtiks: `` ` ;-) PS: it doesn't work in comments :-S

Comment: @diEcho I got it working by SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE 'MyValue' IN (row1, row2) but what if I want to filter something in the query that does not include something like:  AND WHERE row10 IS NOT 'hello'

Comment: @Aaron: `WHERE 'MyValue' NOT IN (row1, row2)`